# Insert a linq-query into DataTable Rows dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datatable

I am currently looking for a way to dynamically insert all fields of a LINQ-Query (excluding the ID-field) into the rows of a DataTable with matching columns. The end goal is to bulkInsert/SQLBulkCopy the DataTable into the Database.

```
var clearing = from line in ReadCSVFile(e.FullPath)
               select new ClearingData
               {
               //About 200 fields are set here SNIP
               };

//Create a DataTable for Bulk Inserting
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Insert the appropriate columns into the DataTable
foreach(var property in typeof(ClearingData).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name != "CSVReportID"))
{
    dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
}           

foreach(ClearingData clear in clearing)
{
//Something like dt.Rows.Add(all Elements in clear.Where(field != "ID"))
}
```

ClearingData is a mapped type from Entity Framework, clearing is a LINQ-Query that imports a 200-meg .CSV and creates an anonymous type containing all rows and fields. There are about 200 fields, which is why I don't want to add the rows by hand.

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: You can use nuget package for bulk insert with entity framework instead of this. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6

Comment: You are indeed correct and your solution works, however I'm still somewhat curious how one would actually convert a LINQ-Query into a DataSet dynamically, so I'll leave this open